# Creating collections of arbitrarily positioned controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have a simple `Border` and `Grid` that is positioned within a `Canvas` container in WPF. The position of the control changes during runtime hence why it resides in the canvas.

The XAML for the control looks something like this:

```
<Border Name="PopupArea"
        Width="130"
        Height="150"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="2"
        CornerRadius="5">
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.5" Color="Black" />
    </Border.Background>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect />
                </Border.Effect>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource SmallWhiteFont}">HELLO WORLD</TextBlock>
            </Border>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

However I now need to be able to create a `Collection` of the above control which I create and destory as required at runtime in code.

My questions are :

A. What is the best way to compose my XAML to create multiple instances of the above control through code? Do I just declare a ContentControl in the resources?

B. Assuming I am correct and a resource template is required. How do I actually use it to create multiple instances of the control in code?

Answer (score 0):

Within XAML I would use an ItemTemplate.
Then I would bind ItemsSource to some observable collection on my viewmodel.

Here's an example taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myTodoList}}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

NOTE:

It is more common to define a DataTemplate in the resources section so it can be a reusable object.

```
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myTodoList}}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTaskTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that as best as I understand a ListBox is rendered as a StackPanel. Because of this the positioning for the individual items inside the canvas no longer works if you use this approach.